# getDirtyAttributes() not showing changes

Tags: craft3, modules

I've got an event listener in a custom plugin where I want to check to see if the users email updated, but it doesnt show that attribute as dirty, even though I know it should be:

```php
Event::on(User::class, User::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE, static function (ModelEvent $event) {
    /** @var \craft\elements\User $user */
    $user = $event->sender;

    Craft::info('USER::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE');

    Craft::info($user->getDirtyAttributes());
});
```

When I update the users name or email from the admin panel, I get an empty array in my logs

> 2021-02-03 17:20:18 [-][25250][-][info][application] USER::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE
>
> 2021-02-03 17:20:18 [-][25250][-][info][application] []

From the API:

> Returns whether an attribute has changed since the element was first loaded.

The way I have read that is whenever something changes on the model, it will be recorded in the above method output

What am I doing wrong/missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entries are currently the only element type which support that method fully.

Comment: That would explain what I'm seeing. What would you suggest I use as a stop-gap? Also, is this something you'd be interested in letting me submit a PR to implement?

Comment: Also, did I overlook where this was specified in the documentation? want to make sure I'm looking at the correct places so I don't end up in this situation again